# remove multiple double quotes inside array

Tags: javascript

I have an array that contains 5 elements and 4 double quotes how do I remove just the double quotes while leaving the rest of the elements.

```
let arr = ["kot"," "," ",","dart","," "];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of `String.trim` and `Array.filter`

`arr = arr.filter(element => element.trim())`

the `trim` method will remove starting and trailing whitespace, so the `" "` strings will be converted to `""`. Empty strings are considered falsy, so they will be removed by the `filter` function.

```js
let arr = ["ruby","javascript","golang","dart","kotlin"," "," "," "," "];

console.log(arr.filter(e => e.trim()));
```